# How does MSTest determine the Outcome of TestCaseResult?

Tags: c#, tfs, mstest, status, testcase

How does MSTest determine the Outcome of TestCaseResult?

As part of

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.**ITestCaseResult**

there is a "**TestOutcome**" property that indicates the outcome of the test result (obviously)... But, what is less obvious, is what the outcomes actually mean...

- What are the triggers?
- What causes the triggers to throw?

decompiled from assembly...

```
    public enum TestOutcome
    {
        Unspecified = 0,
        None = 1,
        Passed = 2,
        Failed = 3,
        Inconclusive = 4,
        Timeout = 5,
        Aborted = 6,
        Blocked = 7,
        NotExecuted = 8,
        Warning = 9,
        Error = 10,
        NotApplicable = 11,
        MaxValue = 12,
        Paused = 12,
    }
```

I am pretty sure that the test harness is responsible for determining how these outcomes are used, but I cant find any documentation describing how, for instance, MSTest knows when you mark a TestResult as "**Blocked**" rather than "**Error** or **Failed**"

Comment: Is there a problem you're trying to solve by asking this, or are you just curious?

Comment: Yes, we are trying to auto generate bugs based on exception signatures. We know why a testCaseResult "Passes", and we think we understand "Failed", but we don't understand how the others are triggered.

We have found that TestCaseResults don't store StackTraces. They do store ErrorMessages but the object has a max character limit of 527bytes and cuts the stacktrace short. (most likely a datastore limitation).

If we understood how these Types were triggered, we could invoke them and sample the output. At the moment, we don't have any sample data to play with.